# Implementing Automatic Filter on SearchView android

Tags: java, android, xml, searchview

I am working on a note application whereby the added notes are displayed in a`listView`. 
I included a search bar as one of the menu items so as to filter individual notes when the user tries to search.
For now, I have implemented the filterable feature for my `listView` but it's not working as expected. It's not filtering automatically when the user starts typing a letter.

The user has to do it manually by clicking on the enter button on his device for the search function to be performed and even when the `searchView` is empty, the `listView`items don't reappear.
How do I make sure that the search function is done automatically when the user starts typing a letter just like the way most search functionalities are?

```
// menumain.xml

    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            app:actionViewClass= "android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:title="@string/search" />



    </menu>

        //Main Activity
           @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
        na.getFilter().filter(query);
        if (!query.equals("")) {
            na.getFilter().filter(query);
            nb.getFilter().filter(query);
        } else {
          mListNotes.setAdapter(na);
            mGridNotes.setAdapter(nb);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
// Note.java
public class Note implements Serializable {

    private long mDateTime; //creation time of the note
    private String mTitle; //title of the note
    private String mContent; //content of the note

    public Note(long dateInMillis, String title, String content) {
        mDateTime = dateInMillis;
        mTitle = title;
        mContent = content;
    }


    public void setDateTime(long dateTime) {
        mDateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        mContent = content;
    }

    public long getDateTime() {
        return mDateTime;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return mContent;
    }
}

    // Note List Adapter

    class NoteListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Note> implements Filterable{
        List<Note> objects;
        private List<Note> mStringFilterList;
         Filter filter;
        private static final int WRAP_CONTENT_LENGTH = 5;
        public NoteListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Note> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            this.objects = objects;
          this.mStringFilterList = objects;

        }

       @Override
      public int getCount() {
          return objects.size();
       }

        @Nullable
       @Override
        public Note getItem(int position) {
           return objects.get(position);
        }

        @Override
       public long getItemId(int position) {
           return position;
       }


        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    ArrayList<Note> tempList= new ArrayList<>();
                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                    if (constraint != null && objects != null) {
                        for(Note singleNote : objects) {
                            if( singleNote.getTitle().contains(constraint))
                                tempList.add(singleNote);
                        }
                        results.values = tempList;
                        results.count = tempList.size();
                    }

                    return results;
                }
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    objects = (ArrayList<Note>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            };
            return filter;
        }

            }

            return convertView;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Do filtering on the `onQueryTextChange` method that'll let you filter the result with each character user types on the searchView

Comment: works now but how do i make the listview items return to normal when the searchView is empty? i need a refresh logic which makes the items come back when there is no text on the SearchView

Comment: pls review my updated code in onQueryTextChange

Answer (score 0):

You need to add filtering code in `onQueryTextChange` method also. This method is called each time a keystroke is fired from keyboard.

Do like this in your main activity on :

```
//Main Activity 
@Override 
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) { 
    na.getFilter().filter(query); 
    nb.getFilter().filter(query); 
    return true; 
} 

@Override 
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    na.getFilter().filter(newText); 
    nb.getFilter().filter(newText); 
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: works now but how do i make the listview items return to normal when the searchView is empty?

Comment: i need a refresh logic which makes the items come back when there is no text on the SearchView

Comment: @Benfight First of all you need to have two lists in adapter one for original items and one for filtered items. then in `performFiltering()` check if `constraints` is empty, if empty just pass `original list` into `filtered list`. And use `filter("")`.